# What network interface is a process using?

Tags: networking, network-interface, socket, interface

Is there a way to find what process is using a given network interface? The title of a related question on here is a bit too specific for my needs.

I need to confirm whether my process is running on the intended network interface.

I am using Scientific Linux 6.

Comment: The sockets of a process can be viewed in /proc/<pid>/fd, this should lead to the interfacea.

Comment: A simple command is *ss -ntp* for TCP and *ss -unp* for UDP ports.

Answer (score 4):

Using `netstat` and `grep` you can see what programs are **actively** using a particular interface (not listening)

Here's what I'd use :

```
sudo netstat -tunape | grep "\(192.168.0.20\)" | grep ESTABLISHED
```

This will output all the programs and their PIDs that use the interface `192.168.0.20`.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the interface in question you can use that name and look among your processes under `/proc`. We recently ran into an issue where we needed to find which VM (qemu) processes were using a specific network interface.

The interface in question was called `enp98s0.134`. That numeric suffix `.134` is the VLAN being used for this interface.

```
$ ip a l enp98s0.134
72: enp98s0.134@enp98s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master storage state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:34:12:a1:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

To find which processes were using this we merely looked through the `/proc` to find which QEMU processes were referencing it.

```
$ for i in $(pgrep qemu); do find /proc/$i -type f | grep enp98s0.134$;done | head
/proc/24217/task/24217/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/24217/task/24217/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
/proc/24217/task/24221/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/24217/task/24221/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
/proc/24217/task/24222/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/24217/task/24222/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
/proc/24217/task/24226/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/24217/task/24226/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
/proc/24217/task/24227/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/24217/task/24227/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
```

The 2nd digit in the path is the PID of the QEMU processes. A similar approach can be used if you happen to not know which process at all:

```
$ find /proc/* -type f | grep enp98s0.134$ | head
/proc/1/task/1/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/1/task/1/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
/proc/1/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/1/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
/proc/10/task/10/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/10/task/10/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
/proc/10/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/10/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
/proc/100/task/100/net/vlan/enp98s0.134
/proc/100/task/100/net/dev_snmp6/enp98s0.134
```

To parse out the PIDs:

```
$ find /proc/* -type f | grep enp98s0.134$ | awk -F/ '{print $3}' | sort -u | head -5
1
10
100
101070
104
```